# pthread condition loop

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

The typical pattern I've seen for using pthread_cond_wait is:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  while (!test)
    pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &lock);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

Why can't an if statement be used instead of a while loop.

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  if (!test)
    pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &lock);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html

> When using condition variables there is always a Boolean predicate involving shared variables associated with each condition wait that is true if the thread should proceed. Spurious wakeups from the pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait() functions may occur. Since the return from pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait() does not imply anything about the value of this predicate, the predicate should be re-evaluated upon such return.

The `while` loop is a very standard way of re-evaluating the predicate, as required by POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` is possible but rarely used. You just would have to be sure that the state of your application is as you come out of the `wait`. Usually you would have to ensure that you'd only use `pthread_cond_signal` at the other end (and not `broadcast`), e.g.

Comment: As per R's answer, spurious wakeups are allowed, which means an if is not guaranteed safe irrespective of using signal over broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons. One is spurious wakeups, as mentioned in other answers. The other is real wakeups. Imagine this:

You have two threads, A and B, blocked on the same condition variable that protects a queue, the queue is empty. Some thread puts a job on the queue, waking thread A. Another thread puts a job on the queue, waking thread B. Thread A starts running first, and does the first job. It gets back to the `if` and sees that the condition is still true (since there's a second job), so it does that job too. Now thread B gets the processor, returning from `pthread_cond_wait`, but the predicate is not false, since the queue is empty.

You only know that the predicate was true when some other thread asked that you be woken up. You have no way to know that it will still be true when you finally do get scheduled and are able to re-acquire the mutex.